# Windows 7, Ignore second plugged in monitor/display.

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I currently have dual monitors, a tv and a nice asus monitor. For some reason one of my programs has a fit after a few hours on dual monitors and will only display if it is shown across both monitors, which is annoying.

How can I ignore my second display, without unplugging it?

When both are plugged in but my tv is powered off, windows still recognizes that display's display area and lets me move applications there. So I wish to totally ignore it somehow, and be able to un-ignore it when I wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on Desktop - choose the `Screen Resolution` option.

From the `Multiple displays` option you can choose to display Windows on any one of the two connected monitors/T.Vs (`Show desktop only on 1` or `Show desktop only on 2`).

A quick keyboard shortcut for switching to just one or to both is `WIN-P`

Comment: Ahhh, success!! I'm pretty sure I knew that too.. I was crawling through the advanced settings banging my head on the wall...

Comment: Good to hear :)